# Excel month to repeat 179 times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to month "Feb" 179 times vertically in excel.
Is there any way I can do it by formula, please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Are you going to need to do this repeatedly? Is there a particular reason you can't just copy one cell, select the remaining 178 and do ctrl+v ?

Comment: Honestly, there is no reason but to understand is there any way that I could it via formula

Comment: What do you mean "by formula"? Something you write in cell A1 that will automatically fill cells A2 to A180? Then no. You can do it with a script though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also try `EXPAND()`.

```
=EXPAND("Feb",179,,"Feb")
```

Comment: More about [Expand function](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-expand-function).

Answer (score 4):

One more:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(179),"Feb")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with an array formula:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(REPT("Feb;", 179), ,";")
```

Comment: Your formula spills 180 cells (rows). More accurately would be `=DROP(TEXTSPLIT(REPT("Feb;",179),,";"),-1)` or `=TEXTSPLIT(REPT("Feb;",178)&"Feb",,";")`.

Comment: In the end, the most reasonable fix is by simply using the 4th argument of TEXTSPLIT: `=TEXTSPLIT(REPT("Feb;",179),,";",1)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Repeat String in Column

- The other day I solved it using this:

  ```
  =INDEX("Feb",SEQUENCE(179,,1,0))
  ```
- I wouldn't post it, but it is equally efficient as the `EXPAND` and `IF-SEQUENCE` solutions. I tested all with 4M cells (1M in 4 columns). It took about 2s.
- And an exotic one:

  ```
  =MAKEARRAY(179,1,LAMBDA(r,c,"Feb"))
  ```
- This one took double the time, so it's a no-go for large data sets.